# How to make a loop for getting input and output

Tags: bash

I have a command line like this:

```
myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta0.grs -o normal/brs0.opm
```

I have 100 `.grs` files and I need to generate 100 `.opm` files.

I want to put the command above into a loop that does the following:

```
myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta0.grs -o normal/brs0.opm 
myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta1.grs -o normal/brs1.opm 
myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta2.grs -o normal/brs2.opm 
myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta3.grs -o normal/brs3.opm 
myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta4.grs -o normal/brs4.opm 

.
.
.
myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta100.grs -o normal/brs100.opm
```

I was trying to make it like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Basic until loop
counter=100
until [ $counter -gt 100 ]
do
myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta100.grs -o normal/brs100.opm

done
echo All done
```

but I could not find a way to set the parameters changes during the loop

In the above command these are constant for each run:

```
myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c
```

The only thing that changes in each loop is the following input and output:

```
normal/sta100.grs 
normal/brs100.opm
```

I have 100 of `sta.grs` in the `normal` folder and I want to create 100 of `brs.opm` in the `normal` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
until ((counter>100))
do
    myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta$counter.grs -o normal/brs$counter.opm
    ((++counter))
done

echo 'All done'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent use case for `GNU parallel`:

```
find normal -name '*.grs' |
parallel myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c {} -o {.}.opm
```

The less code you write, the less errors you make. And this generalizes nicely to cases where your files are named in more complex patterns. And you get parallelization for free (you can get rid of it with `-j1`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of incrementing the counter manually, you could use a for loop like this:

```
for i in {0..100}; do
    myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta"$i".grs -o normal/"$i".opm
done
```

Also, consider that this will sort in an unintuitive way:

```
1.opm
10.opm
100.opm
11.opm
12.opm
```

so maybe use padded numbers everywhere with `for i in {000..100}; do`. This requires Bash 4.0 or newer; if you don't have that, you could do something like

```
for i in {0..100}; do
    printf -v ipad '%03d' "$i"
    myscript constant/tap.txt -n base.dat -c normal/sta"$ipad".grs \
        -o normal/"$ipad".opm
done
```

where the `printf` line puts a padded version of the counter into the `ipad` variable.

(And if you have Bash older than 3.1, you can't use `printf -v` and have to do

```
ipad=$(printf '%03d' "$i")
```

instead.)